# How to change to when statement

Tags: vhdl

can someone help me on how to change this vhdl code to using 'when' statement?

Here is the code that I have written:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sel2_1 is
   port( A, B, SEL : in std_logic;
         outsgnl    : out std_logic);
end sel2_1;

architecture EX1 of sel2_1 is
begin
   outsgnl <= (not SEL and A) or (SEL and B);
end EX1;
```

the simulation result is as follows:
[simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6ihm.jpg)

Comment: i've edit the question above and put the simulation result. i'm trying to change the vhdl code to using when statement and i expect the same exact result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When keyword is used in different VHDL assignments. Assuming `SEL` is only `'0'` or `'1'` you can simpley replace

```
outsgnl <= (not SEL and A) or (SEL and B);
```

by a *selected signal assignment*, often referred as with/select assignment

```
with SEL select outsgnl <=
    A when '0',
    B when others;
```

Alternatively you may use *conditional signal assignment* often referred as when/else

```
outsgnl <= A when SEL = '0' else B;
```

Comment: thank you so much!  it works the same as the simulation i post above.